# Form aligning over different columns

Tags: html, css, forms

I need to make a form page that is divided into two parts: one column with a certain colour on the left and another white column on the right. These two parts are contained in a container class. The form needs to be aligned in a way that the labels are in the coloured column, and the inputs on the right side, in the white column.

The problem appears when I need to align the labels and inputs on either side horizontally. All options I've seen for horizontal aligning call for the labels and inputs to be in the same division or column, but I cannot do this, since I need the design to have the two separate parts and the labels and inputs to align to the dividing line between the two (and scale accordingly).

How could I manage this? Tried using the  choice that included the label column (col-sm-4) and input column (col-sm-8), but the labels did not align horizontally with the inputs that way.

[A mock-up of what I imagine it to look like.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pLNZ0.png)
Added random colours for understandability. The pink box is the left column with labels and the white one is the input column. The line where these two boxes/columns meet is the line with which the labels and inputs need to align to, which is why I can't just make the background some colour|white. The alignment is necessary when scaling. Also, the column should need to become vertically aligned when the window is too small (eg a phone screen), so the label one becomes the upper one and input one is down, which is another reason there needs to be some sort of grid/columns.

Sorry, I have code but it doesn't work as needed currently, so I hope the image helps enough.

Thanks!

Comment: Could you please show us some code (HTML/CSS) to make it easier to answer your question?

Comment: I may be able to help with positioning stuff, but I need a diagram of what you want.

Comment: Is the added picture enough? Pretty sure my code would confuse more than help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update!

Figured it out, instead of two big columns that contain the labels and inputs, i had rows with two col-s next to each other, one containing the label and the other input. Stacked those rows on each other, so they look like two big columns and still align the right way. 
So something like this, stacked many times in one container:

```
<div class="row">
   <div class="col-sm-4 green-bg">
        Address
   </div>
   <div class="col-sm-8 white-bg">
       <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name">
   </div>
</div>
```